# wxPython Popupmenu on a TreeCtrl right click

Tags: wxpython

I would like to have a tree control where I can right click to create a popup menu. When an item menu is clicked, an event is then sent which contains the ItemData from the tree. I have no idea how to go about this. All I have so far is a simple popup menu generation

```
# Panel

def __init__(self, ...):
    # ...
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_TREE_ITEM_RIGHT_CLICK, self.OnRightClick)

def OnRightClick(self, event):
    popupmenu = wx.Menu()
    entries = ['One', 'Two']
    for entry in entries:
        menuItem = popupmenu.Append(-1, entry)
```

How can I get the TreeCtrl ItemData from the TreeEvent? Once I have this data, do I need a custom event to attach it to?

edit: Well getting the item data takes a roundabout way.

```
item = event.GetItem()
itemData = self.tree.GetItemData(item).GetData()
```

Answer (score 5):

Well I got some help on irc. Once I got the item data I just used lambda to wrap one event handler

```
def OnRightClick(self, event):
    """Setup and Open a popup menu."""
    # Get TreeItemData
    item = event.GetItem()
    itemData = self.tree.GetItemData(item).GetData()
    # Create menu
    popupmenu = wx.Menu()
    entries = ['One', 'Two']
    for entry in entries:
        menuItem = popupmenu.Append(-1, entry)
        wrapper = lambda event: self.OnStuff(event, itemData)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, wrapper, menuItem)

    # Show menu
    self.PopupMenu(popupmenu, event.GetPoint())

def OnStuff(self, event, data=None):
    myEvent = events.myCustomEvent(self.GetId(), data=data)
    wx.PostEvent(self, myEvent)
```

Comment: Could you elaborate how myEvent is defined?

Comment: @jake77 I haven't dealt with this in a while, but myEvent can just be any event. I may be able to help more if you're a little more specific, but don't get your hopes up

Comment: I tried your code and it did not run due to missing `events`. So I just replaced it with a print. @Shatnerz, thanks anyway for the fast answer.

Comment: It was meant as a place holder for any arbitrary event

Comment: The popup shows above the cursor, with 2 Menu entries a 50px vertical offset looks goot, at least on gtk, code:
`x,y=event.GetPoint();self.PopupMen(popupmenu,(x,y+50))`